# How to setup cookiecutter-django to run functional tests with Selenium?

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, cookiecutter-django

I am using [Cookiecutter Django](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django) with Docker and Webpack.

I'm struggling to use Selenium for functional tests with the way Cookiecutter Django template is set up.

I have added a Selenium container:

```
selenium_chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    container_name: local_selenium_chrome
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

I am using Django `StaticLiveServerTestCase` in my functional test. This is launching a live Django server on a random port, which I can access like this: `self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)`.

However, the static files are missing (CSS and JS) because they are served from a `node` container in the Cookiecutter Django local setup.

What is the correct way to update my Cookiecutter Django template to be able to run Selenium tests with full static assets available?